# What is the best way to receive data from multiple URL for iot in Apache Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi, real-time-data

I want to receive data from multiple url. You can think, each url is represent one device. I can create flow that starting with getHttp for each device. But this scenario so bad for me. Another option, i can create flow that starting with generateFlowFile(each url defined in this processor), then split, and send this urls to invokeHttp processor. But each url will work in a sequential. So, I can loss data from others when i send request to one url.

What can i do in this case?

**Edit:**
For my use case, firstly, i must receive data from multiple url. Then i will send these data to Kafka after apply some transformations. But I have to get data from almost 50 or more URLs. I need to do this in real time and in a scalable way in a nifi cluster.

Comment: What's your `usecase` is it just receive data and store into HDFS..etc?, Please update your question with more details.

Comment: i have edited my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same flow as mentioned in the question:

**Described Flow in Question:**

```
1.GenerateFlowFile
2.Split Text
3.Extract Text
```

Then feed the success relationship of ExtractText processor to **`RemoteProcessorGroup`**(to distribute the load across clusted).

Then get the flowfile that are distributed feed them to ***`InvokeHTTP`*** processor and **schedule** the processor to **run more than one concurrent** tasks in Scheduling Tab.

Then use ***`PublishKafkaRecord`*** processors and define Record Reader/Writer schema, Change the schedule to run more than one concurrent task.

**Final Flow:**

```
1.GenerateFlowFile
2.SplitText
3.ExtractText
4.RemoteProcessorGroup (or) ConnectionLoadBalance(Starting NiFi-1.8.0)
5.InvokeHTTP //more than one concurrent task
6.RemoteProcessorGroup (or) ConnectionLoadBalance(Starting NiFi-1.8.0) //optinal 
7.PublishKafkaRecord //more than one concurrent task
```

Try with the above flow and i believe Kafka processors are very scalable, give you good performance as you are expected :)

**In addition**

Starting from NiFi-1.8 version we `don't` need to use **`RemoteProcessGroup`** (to distribute the load) as we can configure Connections(relationships) to distribute the load balancing.

Refer to [this](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/load-balancing-across-the-cluster) and [NiFi-5516](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5516) links for more details regards to these `new additions` in NiFi-1.8 version.

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much your answer. Now I'm starting to understand better. If I ask again to make sure I understand;

When I run invokeHttp and PublishKafkaRecord with multiple concurrent task on the entire cluster, can I get data from all the urls fast enough and scalable? (assume that distribute the load is done with relationships).

Finally, assume that i working with Nifi-1.8, RemoteProcessorGroup will be deleted.

Comment: @AdamJ. It all depends on how much data is being processed at one time and 
 distributing the load will not affect any performance instead it helps to process the data `more efficiently` and also we are running more than one **concurrent tasks**. in NiFi-1.8 we don't have to use `RemoteProcessorGroup`, as we can distribute load in relationships. Please do load/performance tests with your data and tune the processors to get most out of NiFi. https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/16461/nifi-understanding-how-to-use-process-groups-and-r.html

Comment: Okey, thank you again. I will create this flow, and then apply load/performance tests. Also, i will edit this question again, and share tests results after apply tests.

Comment: @AdamJ. Great..!!, I forgot to mention it would be good to have load balancing after `InvokeHTTP` processor also, Test out the performance `With Connection Loadbalancing after InvokeHTTP` vs `Without Connection Loadbalancing after InvokeHTTP` and use the load balancing if the performance is significant different.

Comment: Okay, i am gonna try this. Thank you so much again.